# First and Last value before NA

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, logic

I am trying to obtain the first and last value for different segments before an NA value in a vector.  Here is an example:

```
xx = seq(1, 122, by = 1)
xx[c(2:10, 14, 45:60, 120:121)] = NA
```

In turn, my results we would 1; 11 and 13; 15 and 44; 61 and 119; 122.

Comment: @Ronak Shah why the edit if you're not going to provide a solution?

Comment: it is not necessary to provide a solution for editing a question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `c++` function to do some looping will be fast on a large set.

This function returns a 2-column matrix, the first column gives the 'start' of the sequence of numbers, the second column gives the 'end' of the sequence.

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('NumericMatrix naSeq(NumericVector myVec) {

    int n = myVec.size();
    NumericVector starts(n); // pre-allocate
    NumericVector ends(n);   // pre-allocate
    starts.fill(NumericVector::get_na());
    ends.fill(NumericVector::get_na());
    int startCounter = 0;
    int endCounter = 0;
    bool firstNumber = !NumericVector::is_na(myVec[0]); // initialise based on first value

    // groups are considered sequential numbers without an NA between them

    for (int i = 0; i < (n-1); i++) {
        if ( !NumericVector::is_na(myVec[i]) && NumericVector::is_na(myVec[i+1]) ) {
            if (i == 0 && firstNumber) {
                startCounter++;
            }
            ends[endCounter] = i + 1;
            endCounter++;
        }

        if (NumericVector::is_na(myVec[i]) && !NumericVector::is_na(myVec[i+1]) ) {
            if ( i == 0 && !firstNumber){
                endCounter++;
            }
            starts[startCounter] = i + 2;
            startCounter++;
        }
    }


    int matSize = startCounter > endCounter ? startCounter : endCounter; 
    IntegerVector idx = seq(0, matSize);
    NumericMatrix m(matSize, 2);

    starts = starts[idx];
    ends = ends[idx];

    m(_, 0) = starts;
    m(_, 1) = ends;

    return m;

}')

naSeq(xx)
```

which gives

```
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   NA    1
# [2,]   11   13
# [3,]   15   44
# [4,]   61  119
# [5,]  122   NA
```

---

### Benchmarking

If you do care about speed, here's a quick benchmark of the solutions. Note that I'm taking the functions as-is from each answer, regardless of the format (or even content) of the result of each function.

```
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(123)
xx <- seq(1:1e6)
naXX <- sample(xx, size = 1e5)
xx[naXX] <- NA 

mb <- microbenchmark(
    late = { latemail(xx) },
    sym = { naSeq(xx) },
    www = { www(xx) },
    mkr = { mkr(xx) },
    times = 5
)

print(mb, order = "median")

# Unit: milliseconds
# expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#  sym   22.66139   23.26898   27.18414   23.48402   27.85917   38.64716     5
#  www   45.11008   46.69587   55.73575   56.97421   61.63140   68.26719     5
#  mkr  369.69303  384.15262  427.35080  392.26770  469.59242  521.04821     5
# late 2417.21556 2420.25472 2560.41563 2627.19973 2665.19272 2672.21543     5
```

Using

```
latemail <- function(xx) {
    nas <- is.na(xx)
    by(xx[!nas], cumsum(nas)[!nas], function(x) x[unique(c(1,length(x)))] )
}

www <- function(xx) {
    RLE <- rle(is.na(xx))
    L <- RLE$lengths
    Index <- cumsum(L[-length(L)]) + (1:(length(L) - 1) + 1) %% 2

    matrix(c(Index[1], NA, Index[2:length(Index)], NA), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
}

library(dplyr)
mkr <- function(xx) {
    df <- data.frame(xx = xx)
    df %>% mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(xx), ifelse(!is.na(lag(xx)), lag(xx),
                                                                                                 ifelse(!is.na(lead(xx)),lead(xx), NA)), NA)) %>%
        select(value) %>%
        filter(!is.na(value))
}
```

Comment: See my comment to www's answer - you seem to have the same issue - the first group should be `1 to 1` not `1 to 11` for instance. But this does remind me that I need to learn some C++ to speed up these kind of operations.

Comment: @thelatemail - thanks for the pointer. I read "results we would 1; 11 and 13; 15 and 44; 61 and 119; 122" as a 'semi-colon separated' group, then the 'and' separated the groups. I'll update...

Comment: @thelatemail - It really is worth it (learning Rcpp) - very simple when you get the hang of it and the speed improvements are usually good.

Comment: @www - it surprised me how efficient your `rle` method was

Comment: @SymbolixAU Thank you very much for providing this solution.  I tried it on a rather large data set 10M+ records and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

Make a counter that is constant for groups of non-`NA` values - `cumsum(nas)[!nas]`, then take the first and last value in each group of non-`NA` values:

```
nas <- is.na(xx)
by(xx[!nas], cumsum(nas)[!nas], function(x) x[unique(c(1,length(x)))] )

#cumsum(nas)[!nas]: 0
#[1] 1
#--------------
#cumsum(nas)[!nas]: 9
#[1] 11 13
#--------------
#cumsum(nas)[!nas]: 10
#[1] 15 44
#--------------
#cumsum(nas)[!nas]: 26
#[1]  61 119
#--------------
#cumsum(nas)[!nas]: 28
#[1] 122
```

If speed is a concern, `by` can be a fair bit slower than `split`ting and `lapply`ing:

```
lapply(split(xx[!nas], cumsum(nas)[!nas]), function(x) x[unique(c(1,length(x)))] )
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help!  This solution worked the best!  I love stackoverflow!

Comment: just one more question....instead of the results being factors how could I change them to a character?  'as.character'?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution I can think of is using `tidyverse`. First create a `data.frame` using vector from OP. Then add (`mutate`) a column with desired values.

The use of `lead` and `lag` will provide option to get hold of non-NA value from either `previous` or `next` row. The rows corresponding to `NA` will have `NA` value which can be later filter out.

```
library(tidyverse)
xx = seq(1, 122, by = 1)
xx[c(2:10, 14, 45:60, 120:121)] = NA

df <- data.frame(xx = xx)
df %>% mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(xx), ifelse(!is.na(lag(xx)), lag(xx),
                            ifelse(!is.na(lead(xx)),lead(xx), NA)), NA)) %>%
  select(value) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value))

#Result
#  value
#1     1
#2    11
#3    13
#4    44
#5    61
#6   119
#7   122
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rle` and `cumsum`.

```
RLE <- rle(is.na(xx))
L <- RLE$lengths
Index <- c(1, cumsum(L) + (1:length(L) + 1) %% 2)

matrix(Index, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]   11   13
# [3,]   15   44
# [4,]   61  119
# [5,]  122  122
```

**Explanation**

`rle(is.na(xx))` creates the run-length-encoding of `is.na(xx)`, which contains the length of each NA and non-NA group.

```
RLE <- rle(is.na(xx))
RLE
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:9] 1 9 3 1 30 16 59 2 1
#   values : logi [1:9] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE ...
```

`L <- RLE$lengths` extracts the length of each group.

```
L <- RLE$lengths
L
# [1]  1  9  3  1 30 16 59  2  1
```

`cumsum(L)` calculates the cumulative sum all the length to obtain the index.

```
cumsum(L)
# [1]   1  10  13  14  44  60 119 121 122
```

We then need to add one for those even index numbers. So we used `(1:length(L) + 1) %% 2` to specify that.

```
(1:(length(L) - 1) + 1) %% 2
# [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

By combing the above two vectors, we can get the final result.

```
Index <- c(1, cumsum(L) + (1:length(L) + 1) %% 2)
Index
#  [1]   1   1  11  13  15  44  61 119 122 122
```

Finally, I used `matrix(Index, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)` just to view the results more clearly. Each row represents one group. The first column indicates the beginning index of each group, while the second column indicates the end of each group.

```
matrix(Index, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]   11   13
# [3,]   15   44
# [4,]   61  119
# [5,]  122  122
```

Comment: But the groupings aren't `1-11; 13-15; 44-61` etc, so the matrix output is a bit misleading.

Comment: @thelatenmail Thanks for your comment. I think this is the same as the OP’s desired output, so I don’t think this is misleading.

Comment: @thelatemail Wait, I see what you are talking about. I will update my answer to reflect the grouping.

Comment: @thelatemail Please see my update. I decided to add `NA` to the first and last index when creating the matrix output. Thanks again for your comment.

Comment: I hate to be a nuisance, but this still isn't quite right - try it with `xx[c(2:10, 14, 45:60, 120)] = NA` and the last group should be `121 to 122` but ends up being `121 to NA`

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for your comment. Please see my update. My code now will always return the beginning and end of each group. If the group has only one number, the code would return the same index for both the beginning and the end.